# Airline missing in URXVT

Tags: vim, rxvt

I am having a trouble configuring ViM in urxvt: The lower and upper (buffer) bars are transparent.

[image: urxvt]

Things I have tried:

- opened vim in **[tty2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmgkZ.jpg)** and confirmed that it looks **the same as in urxvt**
- it looks *suffiently* right in [terminator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xOG2.png) and [gnome-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JRDr.png)
- used tmux within urxvt: it works as in the other terminals
- modify the `colorsheme`
- modify the `background` color for vim
- modify the Xdefaults
- modify airline theme
- modify the `g:airline_powerline_fonts`
- set different `$TERM` in urxvt
- set different `t_Co` in vimrc
- [gvim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E29Ng.png) look the same as the other terminals

I don't care much for anything else, except for this. It is anoying not being able to see the upper and lower bars plus having a dark blue font (makes it hard to see). For the glyphs, I should probably add in my Xdefaults the correct font.

Additional debugging info:

- `echo $TERM` gives `rxvt-unicode`
- CentOS 7
- ViM version 8.2 (included patches 1-125)
- [My Xdefaults](https://pastebin.com/YfvxJKVQ)
- [My vimrc](https://pastebin.com/BkSVsTfN)

Note: I know this is a recurring problem when using urxvt, but I tried every single solution I could find.

**Edit:** This seems to be a problem in my URXT color support/config. I ran the perl script (contained in [this post](http://scie.nti.st/2008/10/13/get-rxvt-unicode-with-256-color-support-on-ubunut/)) and got this in [urxvt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhPC8.png) and this in [gnome-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lHSK.png).

Comment: Looks like the switching to the alternate screen (provided by the terminal) does not work for you?

Comment: could you elaborate, please?

Comment: The `vi(m)` editor works by switching from the normal terminal screen to a second screen (like a second layer of text) which is normally hidden. After exiting it will switch back, getting you to the original screen. In your screenshot it looks like two screens are visible at the same time, mixed, which makes things unreadable. I do not know how to fix this. However, try typing `Ctrl+L` to see whether that re-draws and fixes the screen.

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: I finally got that working:

When you use `sudo yum install rxvt-unicode` you are installing a version which does not support 256 colors.

What I did was:

1. `sudo yum install rxvt-unicode` (dependency)
2. downloaded urxvt-256color from https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/rxvt-unicode-256color-9.21-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html
3. `chmod +x` and `sudo rpm -i`

This left me with the urxvt and urxvt-256colors.

Comment: I am glad it worked! In order for this to be useful to others please write that up in an answer, making it as useful to others as possible. (If I got you right and you did `chmod` on an RPM file - that's not necessary and you can leave that out.)

Comment: @vgl94 Please post that as an answer, rather than a comment. It will be useful for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got that working:

When you use sudo yum install rxvt-unicode you are installing a version which does not support 256 colors. What I did was:

1. `yum install rxvt-unicode` (dependency)
2. downloaded `urxvt-256color` from [CentOS pkgs repo](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/rxvt-unicode-256color-9.21-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)
3. `rpm -i package_name` This left me with the urxvt and urxvt-256colors.